# CSS - Evenly distributed navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm trying to evenly distribute the navigation bar so it spreads across the entire page as opposed to leaving a gap towards the right hand side as it is currently doing.

How would I be able to achieve this with CSS?

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!--– Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display –-->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <!--– Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling –-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav divider"><li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-20 active"><a title="Find Your Home" href="http://localhost/radleigh/find-your-home/">Find Your Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a title="About Us" href="http://localhost/radleigh/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a title="Helping You Move" href="http://localhost/radleigh/helping-you-move/">Helping You Move</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a title="News" href="http://localhost/radleigh/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a title="Get in Touch" href="http://localhost/radleigh/get-in-touch/">Get in Touch</a></li>
</ul>        </div><!--– /.navbar-collapse –-->
        </div><!--– /.container –-->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
/* Navigation
-------------------------*/
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #002e5d;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#toggle-navbar {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 95px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffcd00;
}

#toggle-navbar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    padding: 0 32px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #FFF;    
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:focus {
    color: #e8e8e8; 
}

.navbar-collapse {
    display: table;
    float: right;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #1b66b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background-color: #1b66b2;
    color: #FFF;
}

.navbar .current_page_item {
    background: #1b66b2;    
    border-right: none !important;
    height: 60px !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-weight: 700;   
}

.navbar .current_page_item:not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0 -1px !important;
}

.navbar .current_page_item a {
    line-height: 40px !important;   
}

.menu-main-menu {
    font-size: 17px;    
}
```

I've made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfj7ummm/

Comment: are you looking like this.? **https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/12/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Bootstrap styles do not support your desired behavior, so you will want to overwrite a couple of them.  For ease, and to prevent these new styles from (potentially) affecting other elements, I have added an `id` field to your navbar:

```
<div id="myNavbar" class="navbar-header">
```

I then overwrite the unwanted styles with my own:

```
#myNavbar {
    float: none;
}
#myNavbar > .navbar-collapse {
    float: none;
}
#menu-main-menu {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu-main-menu > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see in this [jsfiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/xfj7ummm/1/), the navigation tabs are now centered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To evenly distribute your links you can use `display:table` for the `navbar` and `display:table-cell` for the `li` which I would use inside a media query above 768px to avoid altering the navigation on mobile viewports.

There are also some media queries added to compensate for the font-size and length of the link titles.

*You also have some inconsistencies with your HTML. Your closing navbar-header div should be before `.navbar-collapse` not after.

See example Snippet at Full Page.

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #002e5d;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: #1b66b2;
  color: #FFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .current_page_item {
  background: #1b66b2;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #1b66b2;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/radleigh/find-your-home/">Find Your Home</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-20 active"><a title="Find Your Home" href="http://localhost/radleigh/find-your-home/">Find Your Home</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a title="About Us" href="http://localhost/radleigh/about-us/">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a title="Helping You Move" href="http://localhost/radleigh/helping-you-move/">Helping You Move</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a title="News" href="http://localhost/radleigh/news/">News</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a title="Get in Touch" href="http://localhost/radleigh/get-in-touch/">Get in Touch</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks @vanburen - I did actually try this but it messes up the borders between the links

Comment: How are the borders supposed to be?